# Dealing with three 2-D numpy arrays without using loops

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have three 2-D numpy arrays with shape as (3,7).
I want to take the (0,0) element from each of the array, pass these values in a function and store the returned value at the (0,0) index in a new 2-D array.
Then I want to take (0,1) element from each of the array, pass these values to the same function and store the returned value at the (0,1) index of the same new array.

I want to run this for all the columns and then move on to the next row and continue till the end of the array.

The catch here is that I don't want to use loops, just the numpy methods. Been struggling a lot on this lately. Any ideas would be of great help.

Thanks!

I am running a loop like this for now. It gives me back the result for each element in the 1st row only. Here a, b and c are the three 2-D arrays that I mentioned earlier.

```
count = 0
def(a, b, c):
    for i in range(0,7):
        count += -(c[:1,:][i][0]) - (((a[:1,:][0][i]-b[:1,:][i][0])/c[:1,:][i][0]))**2
    return count
```

Comment: Please, add the code you have tried so far with a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @alec_djinn I have added the method that I am using for now.

Comment: Shouldn't the `0` and `i` be swapped since the shape is `(3, 7)` not `(7, 3)`? And your code there is presumably trying to sum over a row, whereas you stated your goal was to get one value per index in the original arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all three arrays are the same shape, and you're operating on each element in the same way, you can easily translate to vetorised NumPy functions like so:

```py
# res is a 2-D array of the same shape as a, b and c
res = -c - ((a - b) / c)**2
```

It looks like in your example code you're trying to sum each row, so you can do this after performing the operations:

```py
count = np.sum(res, axis=1)
```

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice, that's what I was looking for. You got it without me even explaining the question properly. Thanks Aaron!